# Ошибка при NPM RUN BUILD

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

Работаю над проектом, где ReactJS-frontdend и Django-backend. Использую модуль coreapi (npm i coreapi) для работы с API на frontend'e. При билде реакт приложения выскакивает ошибка

```
Failed to minify the code from this file:
    ./node_modules/coreapi/lib/utils.js:7
```

Эта ошибка указывает на этот кусок кода:

```
for (let transport of transports) {
    if (transport.schemes.includes(scheme)) {
        return transport
    }
}
```

Сталкивался ли кто нибудь с этим? Есть предложения как исправить? Переписать этот цикл как нибудь?

Вот полный код функции:

```
const determineTransport = function (transports, url) {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(url)
    const scheme = parsedUrl.protocol.replace(':', '')

    for (let transport of transports) {
        if (transport.schemes.includes(scheme)) {
            return transport
        }
    }

    throw Error(`Unsupported scheme in URL: ${url}`)
}
```

Пробовал изменить цикл for(... of ...) на Array.forEach(...) ничего не изменилось.

Перевел весь код модуля через Babel компилятор в ES2015 и проблема исчезла. Но во многих модулях так же используется ES2016 и сам отчасти на нем и никаких проблем. Почему же с этим модулем такие проблемы?

Comment: попробовать переименовать transports в _t, если _t простой массив - попробовать `for in` [https://learn.javascript.ru/array#%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2](learn.javascript.ru/array)

Comment: @qwabra это не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Давно решил проблему, решил поделится. Пакет `coreapi` был написан на ES6, из-за этого `npm run build` не мог собрать приложение.